# Lógica para sistema de diretórios

Tags: c#, algoritmo, modelagem

Tenho um sistema de diretorios no banco

ex tabela diretorio:

```
id
parentDirID
```

parent dir quer dizer q é um subdiretorio.

Como ficaria então no sistema a função de "copiar" diretorios?
mover diretorios seria apenas atualizar o parentDirID, entao iria apenas mudar de lugar pela logica. 
E para copiar um diretorio com subdiretorios? pois se eu gerar um diretorio novo com id diferente, os subdiretorios do antigo não vao apontar para o novo, e eu tambem não posso criar um ID igual pois ficaria errado. Qual a solução?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o código/modelo para para um para vermos como está fazendo e entender melhor qual é o problema. Talvez seu problema seja outro. Talvez você esteja modelando errado, um diretório não deveria depender da localização do sei pai.

Comment: @bigown ,mas é exatamente assim que está o sistema aqui. Se o parentDir for nulo, então é raiz, se tiver algo ele é filho do mesmo.

Comment: Eu continuo dizendo que você precisa colocar mais informações do seu código/modelo.

Comment: @bigown acabei de postar um print,o mesmo é apenas uma tabela pra diretorio, o resto é arquivos, mas em relação a arquivos esta tudo ok ora copiar e mover, pois nao depende de filhos, mas pra diretorio so consegui mover.

Comment: Isto não mostra o que você está colocando. Eu não sei quais informações vão aí. Não sei o que é esse `REFERENCIA`. No meu entendimento mudar o `PARENT` de um diretório não deveria invalidar os diretórios que apontam para esse diretório como seu `PARENT`. Não vejo porque faria isto. Mas se está fazendo você precisa mostrar. É a última tentativa de obter informações relevantes antes de eu desistir.

Comment: pq o parent aponta para o DIRETORIOGUID entao quando eu copio um diretorio eu adiciono um novo e o mesmo vai com um ID novo por isso as referencias pra esse novo ficam invalidas..Referencia tambem não sei veio no modelo.Ainda nao ultilizei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um diretório copiado é um novo diretório, portanto precisa de um novo Id. Isso vale para 
os filhos também - também será criado um novo diretório para cada filho, portanto cada um precisa de um novo Id.

Conteúdo original da tabela (a indentação é para evidenciar subdiretórios):

```
id 1 - pastaA - parentDirID: null
    id 2 - pastaB - parentDirID: 1
        id 3 - pastaC - parentDirID: 2

id 4 - pastaD - parentDirID: null
    id 5 - pastaE - parentDirID: 4
        id 6 - pastaF - parentDirID: 5
```

Agora copiaremos a `pastaE` para baixo de `pastaB`.

Serão gerados novos diretórios `pastaE` e `pastaF`, portanto novos Ids. Conteúdo da tabela depois da cópia:

```
id 1 - pastaA - parentDirID: null
    id 2 - pastaB - parentDirID: 1
        id 3 - pastaC - parentDirID: 2
        id 7 - pastaE - parentDirID: 2
            id 8 - pastaF - parentDirID: 7

id 4 - pastaD - parentDirID: null
    id 5 - pastaE - parentDirID: 4
        id 6 - pastaF - parentDirID: 5
```

## Conclusão

Ao **mover** um diretório, apenas muda-se o seu *parent ID*.

Ao **copiar** um diretório, um diretório **novo** é criado, portanto precisa de um novo ID. Também é criado um diretório novo para cada subdiretório, e cada um destes subdiretórios novos apontam o seu *parent ID* para o novo Id do pai recém criado.

Quanto aos arquivos, também serão criados novos numa cópia, portanto também receberão novos Ids e novos parent Ids.

## Outra opção de modelagem

A sua modelagem atual pode ser bastante difícil de manter. Eu faria assim:

```
Diretorios
id - caminho 
 1 - pastaA
 2 - pastaA/pastaB
 3 - pastaA/pastaB/pastaC

Arquivos
id - id_diretorio
 1 - 1
 2 - 1
 3 - 2
```

É mais simples - não tem hierarquia de registros, vai poupar bastante código e simplificar a leitura do conteúdo da tabela.

Comment: No caso aqui vou ter que aplicar o modelo atual, pois o sistema ja esta quase concluido,então eu aplico uma função recursiva pra resolver isso e ja era. vlw